# Issue with onload behavior difference between chrome 56 and chrome 60

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I had some application screens break when I tried to test them in chrome 60 that work in chrome 56 and I can demonstrate why with this example html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

function windowOnload() {
    alert("window onload called");
}

function bodyOnload() {
    alert("body onload called");
}
window.onload = windowOnload;
</script>
</head>
<body onload="bodyOnload()">

<h1>on load test</h1>



</body>
</html>
```

In chrome 56 both windowOnload and bodyOnload are called, in chrome 60 only bodyOnload is called.  I fixed the pages that had the issue but was looking for some explanation of why the change and could not find anything in the chrome release notes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a bug in the older version, which was fixed in the newer version. Here's the [bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=659911).

This is specified in the HTML specification of the [`body`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-body-element) element:

> The `onblur`, `onerror`, `onfocus`, `onload`, `onresize`, and `onscroll` event handlers of the `Window` object, exposed on the `body` element, replace the generic event handlers with the same names normally supported by HTML elements.

So when the `<body onload="bodyOnload()">` element is parsed, it performs the equivalent of:

```
window.onload = function() {
    bodyOnload();
};
```

which replaces the `window.onload` property that was set in your Javascript.

Comment: This is my understand also but when your code has been depending on the bug for 5 years to work correctly at some point it becomes a feature.  

I found an easy way to fix it and we didn't have any users complain but I am supposed to document why I had to make the change and would ideally like to point something from google/chrome saying they changed it.

Comment: @SteveBauer here is your bug report : https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=659911 For your docs, you could also just state that because of it, you did support only one browser.

Comment: @SteveBauer According to the bug report, the fixed behavior is consistent with other browsers. So your application shouldn't be working correctly in other browsers.

Comment: Application doesn't support other browsers.  We have a separate project to support other browsers that should have also found the problem but it never did, I have a meeting today to review why not.  I confirmed the application has the same issue in the latest versions of firefox and IE but the screens that break must not be in our browser compatibility regression tests which is only a subset of the full regression test, which still doesn't test everything.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Tailoring applications to specific browsers is generally a bad idea. Write standard-compliant code and it should generally work in all browsers.